# Access S3 files from Azure Synapse Notebook

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, azure-databricks, azure-synapse

Goal:
Move a lot of files from AWS S3 to ADLS Gen2 using Azure Synapse as fast as possible using parameterized regex expression for filename pattern using Synapse Notebook.

What I tried so far:

1. I know to access ADLS gen2, we can use
   mssparkutils.fs.ls('abfss://container_name@storage_account_name.blob.core.windows.net/foldername') works but what is the equivalent to access S3 ?
2. I used mssparkutils.credentials.getsecret('AKV name','secretname') and mssparkutils.credentials.getsecret('AKV name','secret key id') to fetch secret details in the Synapse notebook but unable configure S3 to Synapse.

Question: Do I have to use the existing linked service using the credentials.getFullConnectionString(LinkedService) API ?
In short, my question is, How do I configure connectivity to S3  from within Synapse Notebook?

Comment: Can you reformat your post to be a single question + bullet points for what you have tried? This seems like a very confusing way.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Here edited now.

Comment: Are you writing your code in Python or some other language?  If so, I would suggest looking at the AWS Python SDK. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html

Comment: @KenWMSFT yes, pyspark

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question here. AzCopy worked.Below is the link which helped me finish the task. The steps are as follows.

1. Install AzCopy on your machine.
2. Goto your terminal and goto the directory where the executeable is installed; run "AzCopy Login"; use Azure Active Directory credentials in your browser using the link from terminal message..Use the CODE provided in the terminal.
3. Authorize with S3 using below
   set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
   set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
4. For ADLS Gen2, you are already done in step-2
5. Use the commands (which ever suits your need) from the link below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-s3